# How to add app icon badge in xamarin forms wpf application

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.wpf

I need to show unread notification count on a badge in xamarin forms wpf app icon. I have tried with `'xam.plugin.badge'` and `'xamarin.badge.plugin'` NuGet packages but no luck. I am getting below exception:

**Exception :**

> This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this
>   assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main
>   application project in order to reference the platform-specific
>   implementation

.

Please suggest any idea to add badge count in app icon in xamarin forms wpf application.

Comment: You can check this: https://github.com/alexrainman/badge

Comment: I have already tried with that but still getting the same exception (what I have mentioned in the question).

Comment: have you installed the package in the PCL?

Comment: Yes. I have installed in both pcl and wpf projects.

Comment: Can you provide a demo?  I can test it for you.